# Why is inline styling OK with bootstrap?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am doing an online course on frontend, I have just started getting to know bootstrap 4 and flexbox. As far as I understand, to do inline styling is something that is considered bad practice. What I mean is this:

```
<button style="color: white; border: 5px solid red;"> Press me! </button>
```

And I like that the good practice is to not do this, mainly because of readability. What I don't understand is why the button above is not a good practice but the code here is considered good practice

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg d-flex justify-content-center> Press me! </button>
```

Just to clarify I do understand that the style that I used in the example doesn't do the same thing as the one using bootstrap. I am just interested in why one is OK and the other one is not.

The only thing that I have come up with is that since bootstrap is using `class=""` it's probably not inline styling.

Comment: That's *not* inline styling. They're just *classes*, the stylesheet that maps them to styles is elsewhere.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Okay, so it's not in a `style` attribute, but `justify-content-center` still seems pretty inline-stylistic to me. It describes _how the content should look_, not _what it is_.

Comment: Okey but another one then just to take something that´s a little more like inline styling. still a class but only with one purpouse 

<button style="background: yellow;" Click me</button>
<button class="bg-warning"> Click me</button>

I am just curious because I want to learn the right way from the beginning.

Hope you have a great day and thank you for your awnser!

Comment: Imagine if you went to a restaurant with a dress code that said "no hats", and someone pointed to the box on their head and said, "This isn't a hat. It's a box." That seems equivalent to saying that Bootstrap classes are not online styling. They have all of the negatives of online styling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first instance is inline styling:

```
<button style="color: white; border: 5px solid red;"> Press me! </button>
```

and the second has several classes that are styled in a separate css file:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg d-flex justify-content-center> Press me! </button>
```

One of the main reasons that it is bad practice to use inline styles is because they can override the styles that exist in the separate CSS file and become hard to track once your CSS becomes more complex. Also, your code becomes more difficult to maintain when you use inline styles. For example, if you had several buttons in your HTML that were each individually styled with inline styles and you decided to change one of the styles you would then have to change the style for each individual button, whereas if you gave them all the same class and styled that class in a separate CSS file, then you can change the color once and it will update all of your buttons.

For example (bad practice):

**HTML**

```
<button style="background-color: dodgerblue;">Click here</button>
<button style="background-color: dodgerblue;">Click here</button>
<button style="background-color: dodgerblue;">Click here</button>
<button style="background-color: dodgerblue;">Click here</button>
```

vs (good practice):

**HTML**

```
<button id="btn-one" class="button">Click here</button>
<button id="btn-two" class="button">Click here</button>
<button id="btn-three" class="button">Click here</button>
<button id="btn-four" class="button">Click here</button>
```

**CSS**

```
.button {
    background-color: dodgerblue;
}
```

You can read more about CSS styling [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp).

Comment: Thank you very much for taking your time and clarifying this! It´s perfectly clear now. I thought that it was only for readability that one shouldn´t use inline styling. thank you again for taking your time to explain! 
hope you have a great day!

Comment: I think this still begs the question. "If you had several buttons in your HTML that were each individually styled with inline styles and you decided to change one of the styles you would then have to change the style for each individual button." Okay, but that is just as much true for Bootstrap classes, isn't it? If you want to change those buttons to have a different relative width, wouldn't you normally change the class on every one of the buttons?